# Order of multiple extensions in JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

If I use more than one extension with JUnit 5, whats the order? Ideally the order int the `@ExtendsWith` annotation is respected, but I could not find any documentation about that.

Example:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, InitH2.class})
public class VmRepositoryIntegrationTest {
  // Test implemenations
}
```

So in this example I need Spring to set up the DB connection before I cann initialize the DB.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [§5.2.1 of the JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative):

> ...
>
> Multiple extensions can be registered together like this:
>
> ```
> @ExtendWith({ DatabaseExtension.class, WebServerExtension.class })
> class MyFirstTests {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> As an alternative, multiple extensions can be registered separately like this:
>
> ```
> @ExtendWith(DatabaseExtension.class)
> @ExtendWith(WebServerExtension.class)
> class MySecondTests {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> > *Extension Registration Order*
> >
> > Extensions registered declaratively via `@ExtendWith` at the class level, method level, or parameter level will be executed in the order in which they are declared in the source code. For example, the execution of tests in both `MyFirstTests` and `MySecondTests` will be extended by the `DatabaseExtension` and `WebServerExtension`, **in exactly that order**.